# Data normalization in SQL (Parent-Child)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Yesterday I had an on-site interview for a SQL developer position where an interviewer asked me a question which I was unable to answer convincingly. I would appreciate if anyone can help me out with the correct solutions.

Interviewer asked "I have an application and database that needs to be normalized for the future application development. Currently, I have a table (Original) that I want you to convert over to 2 tables with a parent-child relationship (Parent and Child).

> The stucture of the Original table is like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Original(
   ID [varchar](11) NOT NULL,
   SourceDatabase [varchar](10) NULL,
   CompanyName [varchar](25) NULL,
   Address [nvarchar](30) NULL,
   City [char](25) NULL,
   State [char](2) NULL,
   Zip [char](9) NULL
)

--Test Data

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Original]
                   ([ID]
                   ,[SourceDatabase]
                   ,[CompanyName]
                   ,[Address]
                   ,[City]
                   ,[State]
                   ,[Zip])
                   VALUES
                    ('1000000001','ORACLE', 'Microsoft', '123 ABC', 'EDISON', 'NJ', '10000' )
                  , ('1000000001','DB2', 'Microsoft', '123 ABC', 'EDISON', 'NJ', '10000' )
                  , ('1000000024','ORACLE', 'Microsoft', '456 ABC', 'EDISON', 'NJ', '10000' )
                  , ('1000000035','DB2', 'LinkedIn', '123 ABC', 'Mountain View', 'CA', '10056' )
                  , ('1000000002','MSSQL', 'GOOGLE', '456 9th Street', 'PROVIDENCE', 'RI', '10001' )
                  , ('1000000003','MSSQL', 'APPLE', '3100 EAST End Ave,Suite 70729', 'GREENWICH', 'CT', '10002' )
```

Answer the following questions:-

> 1) What are the attributes that I will need for defining a parent and a child table
>
> 2) Will LinkedIn have the same parent ID as that of Microsoft(LinkedIn is a subsidiary of Microsoft)?

3) Will the sample data 1,2 and 3 have a same parent_ID?  "

Thanks!

Comment: This is a horrible interview question. I would have asked the interviewer why they think that splitting this into just 2 tables is normalized. And depending on the usage this table could very well already be normalized. Or was this somehow framed with some sort of clarification about what they are looking for. I hate these kinds of interview questions that are so vague you nearly have to read their mind.

Comment: you have to read their mind - just like you do with real folks trying to give you requirements :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Sean, splitting into two tables doesn't make sense. Maybe it was a trick question. In my opinion, you'd need to split it into 4 tables as in the following diagram:

[image]

You separate address from company as companies might share the same address, reference address from company table. Databases go into their own table. And you bring this all together by a multi-to-multi link between companies and databases that they use.

That, of course, is still an over-simplification as you could further normalize the whole address by splitting City / State into separate tables...